# How can I run a userform from a macro?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I developed many UDFs and macros in VBA for Excel 2016. One of my macros uses an Inputbox to get data used subsequently by the macro. I want to replace the Inputbox with a user form. I have created the user form, with one text box. I want to activate the user form, populating the text box with the default data, and return the text box data to the macro when OK is selected. I have searched extensively for an end-to-end example for all the the code needed to do this, with no luck. Does an example for this simple problem exist?

Comment: To get a userform to open use `userformname.show`.  Look up Userform_Initialize event for the code that executes when a userform opens.  In this sub you can write the things you want to happen such as filling in the default data.

Comment: Research the use of `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize`...it is this routine that would hold your text box default value assignment code (as in `Me.myTextBox.value = "test"`)

Comment: `Private Sub btnOK_Click()` (replacing btnOK with the actual name of your OK button) would hold the code that moves the value of `Me.myTextBox` into your cell of choice.

Comment: I tried using the userform_Initialize sub. It did not set the initial value. Then I tried setting it immediately before invoking .show; that worked. Sorry, I would attach the code but I see no way to do it.

Comment: Add your code to your original question (not in a comment). Add your code, select it, then click the `{}` in the toolbar. Or, if it's just a few lines, indent your lines of code with 4 spaces. There are question-posting instructions somewhere here on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As it turns out, my eyesight is not what it once was, and I did not see the 2 drop down lists at the top of the code window when I selected 'View Code' for the object. Once I got there I was able to follow the flow and used stackoverflow to find how to use global variables to pass values into the form from the invoking macro and back out of the form. Also, thanks for the tip on including code. I had searched stackoverflow for advice on how to do it and I must have misunderstood what I found. Again, many thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how you can pass the value to a form and get the result back. The approach uses `Scripting.Dictionary` object created within standard module scope and passed to userform to allow values to be changed. So it makes possible to send the default values to userform, and keep the result values in the dictionary even after the userform is closed and unloaded. You may have multiple values, just add the necessary quantity of keys to the dictionary, e. g. `oData("property1")`, `oData("property2")`, etc.

Add a standard module to the project and put the below code into it:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim oData

    ' Set default value and show form
    Set oData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oData("") = "Some default text"
    UserForm1.ShowForm oData
    ' Wait until user close form
    Do While IsUserFormLoaded("UserForm1")
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' Output returned value
    MsgBox oData("")

End Sub

Function IsUserFormLoaded(UserFormName As String) As Boolean

    Dim oUF As Object

    For Each oUF In UserForms
        If LCase(oUF.Name) = LCase(UserFormName) Then
            IsUserFormLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Add a userform module named `UserForm1` to the project, place controls as shown:

[image: userform]

And put the below code into the userform module :

```vb
Private opData

Public Sub ShowForm(oData)

    Set opData = oData
    Me.TextBox1.Value = opData("")
    Me.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    If TypeName(opData) <> "Dictionary" Then Set opData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    opData("") = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Property to your user form. For this answer, let us use the following code within the user form.

```
Public Property Get MyResult() As String
    ' You may want to do any manipulation here
    ' including converting to a number, in which case the return type should be changed (*)
    MyResult = TextBox1.Text
End Property
```

(*) If you are doing conversion, you can have another function in your user form to disable the "OK" button until they have valid convertible data in the text box.

You also want to know if they have hit "Cancel"

```
Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = pCancelled ' Declare pCancelled as a Boolean in the scope of the form
End Property

Public Sub CancelButton_Click() ' Standard click event for the button
    pCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Public Sub OKButton_Click() ' Standard click event for the button
    pCancelled = False
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

In your calling macro

```
MyForm.Show ' This is modal, so will block execution until a response is provided
If Not MyForm.Cancelled Then
    Debug.Print MyForm.MyResult
    'Do something with MyForm.MyResult
End If
UnLoad MyForm ' assuming you do not want to re-use this form as part of your logic.
```